# Selecting new item in bootstrap dropdown doesn't clear previous selection

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following code sample behaves as expected except for one problem.  As you can see, I have two menu items, the first of which is a dropdown that lists dates.  When making selections within this dropdown, my previous selections remain highlighted.  I would like it to behave such that when making a 2nd selection, it removes previous selections.  I can probably force the deselection using js/jquery, but suspect there's more Bootstrap friendly way to do this.  In fact, I get the proper behavior on the higher level menu.

```
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menus&nbsp;
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#">1/8/2016</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#">1/9/2016</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#">1/10/2016</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab"       href="#tab_menu_item2">MenuItem2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

After Turnips suggestion to remove the nav from the dropdown, I did so.  I'm still having the same problem though.  Here's what that section looks like now.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu scroll-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a  data-toggle="tab" href="#">1/8/2016</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">   
                        <a  data-toggle="tab" href="#">1/9/2016</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">   
                        <a  data-toggle="tab" href="#">1/10/2016</a>
                    </li>
```

Comment: Is there any reason that you are nesting a `nav` within a `dropdown-menu`? This is the cause of your issue. Remove the `nav` and it works properly: http://www.bootply.com/ggpdA2XqH5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove dropdown class from your list.. and why are you adding class navbar-link? :/

```
   <ul class="dropdown-menu nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="tab" href="#">1/8/2016</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="tab" href="#">1/9/2016</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="tab"  href="#">1/10/2016</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks mercy, that solved the problem.  I didn't have navbar-link class in there, unless you're referring to nav-link.  I think I put that in there while trying to figure this out myself.  It's out now though.  Thanks again.

Comment: np. I recommend you to look at bootstrap documentation really good. I think you don't need to use "dropdown" classes and "nav" classes  together.